# Escrever na "Linha de Comandos" pelo C#

Tags: c#

Boas,
Tenho um programa, que recorre à Linha de Comandos, mas só consigo fazer com que escreva "uma linha", e precisava que escrevesse mais que uma sem apagar o que já foi escrito...

O que tenho até agora:

**CÓDIGO**

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process processo = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            processo.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("comspec");
            processo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            processo.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/K IPCONFIG");
            processo.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/K OPENSSL");

            processo.Start();
            processo.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você deseja e qual é o problema.

Comment: O problema é que o programa neste momento abre a Linha de Comandos, faz o "IPCONFIG" e depois faz o OPENSSL mas apaga o IPCONFIG...

Answer (score 1):

Utilize um `StreamWriter` para mandar vários comandos em sequência:

```
Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;

    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();

    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("IPCONFIG");
            sw.WriteLine("OPENSSL");
        }
    }
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net

Answer (score 0):

Talvez se você alterar seu código:

```
processo.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/K IPCONFIG");
processo.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/K OPENSSL");
```

por esse:

```
processo.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/K IPCONFIG & /K OPENSSL");
```

Possa resolver o seu problema.